# Why vfs_write() adds arbitrary number of zero bytes

Tags: file, linux-kernel, kernel-module, vfs

I am on the kernel 2.6.37 on an embedded system writing some very specific module driver. And I need to store some data into a file. So, when the module is 'insmoded' I do:

```
static struct file *filp;
static loff_t pos, mycnt;

static __init int mymodule_init(void) {
oldfs = get_fs();
set_fs(get_ds());
filp = filp_open("/home/mydata.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644);
set_fs(oldfs);
pos = 0; mycnt=0;
......
```

and then, when needed, the function to write data is called:

```
static int mywrite(const char __user *buf, size_t count) {
char str[256]; int i, j;
mm_segment_t oldfs;
int ret;
//Filter out zeroes, if exist
for(i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    if (i == count) break;
    if (buf[i] == 0) break;
    str[i+1] = buf[i];
}
str[0]=i++;  //Put length in a first byte
//Checking for zeroes ------
for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (str[j] == 0) {
        printk("0 exist!\n");
        str[j] = 0x02; }
}
//Write 'str' to the file ------
oldfs = get_fs();
set_fs(get_ds());
pos = mycnt;
ret = vfs_write(filp, str, i, &pos);
filp->f_pos = pos;
mycnt += i;
if (mycnt != pos) {
    pos = mycnt;
    vfs_llseek(filp, pos, SEEK_SET);
    printk("Corrected!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n"); }
set_fs(oldfs);
//Checking for zeroes again ------
for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (str[j] == 0)
        printk("0 exist!\n");
}
return count;
}
```

Now, the problem is that the resulting file contains sometimes (rare) blocks of zeroes which shouldn't be there. You can see in the writing function code special code to check that there is no zeroes, only supposed ASCII normal text. Also the first byte of each string contains its length. And looking into the file I can see that no zeroes are counted by it. Still, these zeroes are there.
Also, I compared the 'pos' after vfs_write with expected value - it differs exactly the same number of times as zeroes are inserted (3 times in my test example of 20KB file). And "correction" does not work...
So, what do I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe check `ret`? It should equal `i` if it wrote the whole amount.

Comment: Why do you use `__user` attribute for the `buf` parameter of function `mywrite`? Normally, this attributes marks memory as accessible from the user space. But such kind of data should be dereferenced directly (as you do in `str[i+1] = buf[i];` line). So, whether `buf` points to the user are or to the kernel area?

Comment: Ian Abbott - thanks, ```ret``` should be checked, you are right. But it is always the same as i, even when ```mycnt != pos```. Very strange!!!    
Tsyvarev - thanks, you are right - this descriptor is the remainings from the other driver I took for the base. I removed the ```__user```, but this didn't help...

Comment: It seems your `mywrite` function is called many times, but we can only *guess* how it is called and with which parameters (e.g. you still haven't specified, whether its `buf` parameter points to the user or to the kernel area). Please, prepare [mcve], which would include **complete** code of the kernel module which **reproduces** the problem. If reproducing of the problem requires an interaction with the user, then describe a scenario of that interaction too.

Comment: ```mywrite``` function is called from the console driver each time it has a string to print. ```buf, count``` are the buffer with the line from console driver and its length. The original complicated multi functional driver developed 10 years ago, called ```ttyrpl```. I don't need all its options, I reduced it to this function only. The problem with reproducible example is that the  console driver needs to be patched to call this function. I don't understand how can I transfer this. As for my module - it is 99% here: ```__init``` is here, while ```__exit``` is not so important, I  think....

Comment: Well, so it is a console driver... It is better than nothing. Please, incorporate this information into the **question post**: On Stack Overflow a question post should contain **all relevant information**; the comments are *secondary*. That is, for understand your problem one should understand behavior of a console driver. I have no such knowledge. My best guess is that a driver calls your `mywrite` function **in parallel** (from different threads at the same time). But your code cannot work in parallel. E.g. it has unprotected `mycnt` variable. Try to protect your code with a mutex.

Comment: What makes me crazy is that write operation writes correct data. Just sometimes adds THE SAME as the line length number of zeroes at the end. I test by insmoding the driver just after mounting root FS and till the first prompt - I have 4 constant places where these zeroes are added.

Comment: Tsyvarev - you are genius. Sure this is the problem!!!!! 1001 thanks!!! This is the first time I deal with file writing from withing the kernel - this drew my attention in wrong direction.